# Maintaining a reliable session in express

Tags: node.js, session, express

I am using Nodejs and express to create a web app. But i am finding some difficulty in maintaining  session. i can use `req.session.userid = userid` , but it is not so reliable. if the server goes down for some time and it has to reboot, the session will be lost.. Is there any way to store the session more effectively?

Comment: [_"Warning The default server-side session storage, MemoryStore, is purposely not designed for a production environment"_](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer using the npm module called "connect-mongodb-session". It uses mongodb to store all the sessions. Go to your project directory and install "connect-mongodb-session" using

> sudo npm install connect-mongodb-session

And add this to your package.json as dependencies.  and this is how you can use it..

Sample code...

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var MongoDBStore = require('connect-mongodb-session')(session);

var app = express();
var store = new MongoDBStore({ 
    uri: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/connect_mongodb_session_test',
    collection: 'mySessions'
});

// Catch errors 
store.on('error', function(error) {
    assert.ifError(error);
    assert.ok(false);
});

app.use(require('express-session')({
    secret: 'This is a secret',
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 // 1 week 
    },
    store: store
}));

server = app.listen(3000);
```

And you are good to go.. use req.session when ever you want, and your sesion will be stored save in mongodb.

for example..

```
app.post("/login",function(req,res){
    //validate login
    req.session.userid = userid;
})
```

even if the server has to reboot, your session will not be lost.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use a database as stated above, or use the in memory store, like redis. Redis is the preferred way to go when handling user session, since its several factors faster then reading from disk.

Additionally, you may want to look into Json Web Token, so you don't have to store sessions at all, rather just keep a reference to the user token in your database (or redis). This will allow you to easily authenticate on mobile. It can also help prevent csrf attacks if you store the token on a users localstorage (rather then cookie)

You can read about them here: https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-ins-and-outs-of-token-based-authentication, https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-anatomy-of-a-json-web-token, https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens

Comment: Here is a simple example using JWT and express: https://github.com/auth0/nodejs-jwt-authentication-sample